# How to relate the y-axis of different types of graphs?

Tags: highcharts, yaxis

I want to use two types of graphics in one, and the same categories in y-axis for both.

```
//My code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cyt8caLz/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "What do I have to do to have the same values on the y-axis?" - have the values be the same. I am honestly not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: It's true wergeld, I apologize for my English. If you see my code, you will see a column graph and a line graph, the y-axis of the column graph reaches 100 and the line graph reaches 140. How can I make the y-axis of both graphs coordinate ?, ie have the same maximum. if in both graphs I establish a data 95 (for example), they must be united at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use the [`yAxis.linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo) property. From the docs:

> Index of another axis that this axis is linked to. When an axis is
>   linked to a master axis, it will take the same extremes as the master,
>   but as assigned by min or max or by setExtremes. It can be used to
>   show additional info, or to ease reading the chart by duplicating the
>   scales.

So you could do something like:

```
...
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            max: 100,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        tickInterval: 10
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Toneladas'
        },
        linkedTo: 0
    }],
...
```